# Sum function referenced to column number VBA

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, syntax-error

I need to reference columns by number in Sum function (i.e. Column B =2, C=3, E=5, etc)

i tried this code but it didn't work (ColN is the column number read from a listbox index)

```
Range("M5") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(ColN& "2" : ColN&"5"))) '(F2:F5) for example
```

I prefer also to use formulaR1C1 cos this function needs to be applied for the rest of the rows (i.e the next cell would be the sum of F3:F6 and so on)

All help to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Range("M5") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(5, 6)))
```

The `Cells` functions accepts a row and column parameter, which is similar to what you want for R1C1 notation. In this case, `6` means column 6, i.e. column `F`. In your case, you have `colN` as a column number, so you could do this:

```
'Dim colN As Long
'colN = 6 ' read from a listbox index in your case, for example
Range("M5") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, colN), Cells(5, colN)))
```